# deleting some text from a JSON Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array, which looks like this.

```
{"sample":[{"errors":["Invalid Data: 123, abc, 2222"]}
```

How can I delete "123,". The output should look like

```
{"sample":[{"errors":["Invalid Data: abc, 2222"]
```

Thanks for your inputs

Regards
Giri

Comment: `object.sample[0].errors[0].replace('123','')` -> https://jsfiddle.net/dsdj7hzz/

Comment: my_json.sample[0].errors[0].replace('123','')

Comment: @adeneo Your code is missing a step. OP says they have JSON, not a JavaScript object.

Comment: @JordanRunning - actually, it says "JSON array", as there's no such thing, I assumed the OP, as so many others, don't really know what JSON is, and is confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/suykyLce/

```
var o = {
    "sample": [
        {"errors": ["Invalid Data: 123, abc, 2222"]}
    ]
};

var ret = o.sample.map( sampleItem => {
    sampleItem.errors = sampleItem.errors.map( errorData => {
        return errorData.replace(/^(.*):.*?\,/, '$1:');
    });
   return sampleItem;
});
```

I did consider you have multiple objects in both of arrays, not sure if it's true

Answer (score -1):

```
var SampleObj = {"sample":[{"errors":["Invalid Data: 123, abc, 2222"]}]};
console.log(SampleObj.sample[0].errors[0].replace(/123,/g, ''));
```

searches for a `123,` match in errors and replaces with null.
your object is also missing a `]` and `}` at the end.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please also provide an explanation to OP to explain your answer.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].